# Why did Jesus said she is come to anoint my body to the burying?

Tags: nature-of-god, terminology, new-testament, prophecy

What is the significant of Burying  . 
In Hebrew tradition anoint of oil will be done to dead person in their grave.

Comment: Can you please clarify what the question is?

Comment: What is the need of burying ?

Comment: Burying is the normal thing done to a dead body.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you’re asking correctly, I don’t think that the anointing of oil was the actual burial. Jesus was buried in the tomb. 
Jesus was buried because 
 1. It was the normal thing to do
 2. It was prophesied in Isaiah 53:9

> “And he made his grave with the wicked, and with the rich in his death; because he had done no violence, neither was any deceit in his mouth.” Isaiah 53:9 KJV
>
> “And they made his grave with the wicked and with a rich man in his death, although he had done no violence, and there was no deceit in his mouth.” Isaiah 53:9 ESV

The rich refers to Joseph of Arimathea. It was Joseph’s tomb that Jesus was buried in.

Now if you’re asking what the significance of burial in general is, I can’t answer that, but I’d say it’s out of tradition, cleanliness, and respect.

The significance of the oil is probably a different question, and someone else may be able to answer that. Perhaps the significance of those few verses in Mark 14 was only a lesson on materialism.

Answer (score 1):

"burying" here just means "to put into the grave", not necessarily "under the earth". Jesus died and was buried in a cave, before his resurrection. Talking about his burial is anouncing to his disciples that he is going to die. (as he does many times in the NT)

Comment: Verily I say unto you, Wheresoever this gospel shall be preached throughout the whole world, this also that she hath done shall be spoken of for a memorial of her.

Comment: Jesus also said this shall be spoken for a memorial of her